# Datalabels text overflow from plot area in highchart's pie chart

Tags: highcharts

In my highchart's pie chart datalabels working properly when width and height is default **(600*400)**, 
but while change the height and width in custom manner the datalabel text (**Internet Explorer some text**) overflow from plot are and hide.

BTW i used the option

```
dataLabels: {
    crop:false,
    overflow:'none'
}
```

for avoiding overflow but can't

[image]

here my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Murali_Kaliappan/g4hpgotz/16/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the problem here is `size` parameter.

From the **API** (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.size):

> The default behaviour (as of 3.0) is to scale to the plot area and
>   give room for data labels within the plot area.

So if you manually set it to `100%` data labels can be rendered outside of the plot area - Highcharts won't try to find an optimal value for `size` parameter.

Your demo works fine if you preserve the default value of `size`: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zjaa7y81/